# Default Excel template not picked when exporting to excel from another application

Tags: excel, templates, export, vba

I made an Excel template to let the user have some macros available by default.
When I open a **new Excel workbook**, everithing goes well and the macro shows in the macro list and I can use it correctly.

When I **generate the workbook from another application** (e.g. exporting data from MS Access to Excel), the macro is not available in the generated workbook, so I think the tamplate is somehow not picked.

My template is a MS Excel 2010 `Macro-Enabled template (.xltm)`.
I named it `Book.xltm`.
I placed it in the `XLStart` folder in my profile.

Comment: For completeness, as I can state on my environment, in older versions of Office (pre 2007) this approach was successfully adopted: the macro was available in the macro list of the exported document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default template is only used when creating a new workbook from within Excel, not from other applications.

To add your macro to a worksheet created in VBA, first save the macro sheet as the type XLAM (or XLA for compatability with Excel 2003).

Assuming the macro is saved as *MyMacro.xlam* and your workbook is referenced by the variable *MyWb*

```
Set MyAddin = MyWb.Application.Addins.Add("MyMacro.xlam")
MyAddin.Installed=True
```

You can now reference the macro in the new workbook.

Comment: Where do I have to put the code to 'register' the Add-In? Will I be able to have it available as a default of do I have to reference it in every workbook?

Comment: Actually, I've over-complicated this (reflection during my lunch break). If you save your macros as an add-in, you can load them once from the menu, as one loads other add-ins. There may well be another issue with the improved security Microsoft introduced starting with Office 2007...